# Azure DevOps nuget artifact delay

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, delay, devops

We have a dotNET pipeline set up as a class library that the pipeline builds into a nupkg file and pushes to our Azure DevOps hosted artifact library. This works fine, and if we navigate to the Artifacts tab immediately after the build completes we can see the new package version as expected.

However, what we are seeing is anywhere from a 0 to 30-minute delay before we can consume said package using nuget. Have tried consuming it both on my local development machine and also as part of another pipeline in Azure DevOps and neither of them can access the new package version.

The trick so far seems to be, wait for the nuget package to build, then wait 30 minutes to use it.

Has anybody else experienced this delay? Is there some eventual consistency happening between the Azure DevOps UI and its nuget server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal, that is how it works.

When you push a nuget to a repository (Artifacts) in your scenario a lot of things are happening behind the scenes. Some of them would be:

1. Version validation
2. Virus checks
3. Package indexing for searching

This processes usually take from a couple of minutes to half an hour depending on the load of the nuget server. This is the reason your nuget is not immediately available. For instance, when publishing to nuget.org, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package#package-validation-and-indexing), "package validation and indexing usually takes under 15 minutes".

Comment: does this delay happen also for Python packages uploaded via Twine??

Comment: just to pint out that the MS documentation mentioned above refers to up to 30 minutes when publishing to nuget.org rather than to a Azure DevOps feed, in my experience it usually a lot quicker on Azure DevOps, with maximum delays of up to 10 minutes

Comment: @Techromancer, agreed. I've edited the answer in order to make that clear. In time, I couldn't find any documentation with the same information for the Azure Artifacts service (currently experiencing 15~30 min of delay), by chance did you find any?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Thing is that I am able to build my dependent project on my local machine directly after publishing the package from a build pipeline. But the agent with the exact same source version as on my local build will fail the build because it can't find the package. After 30 minutes it works...

Comment: @dandev486, no, I haven't